# Main server fails and I want my backup server to take over

Tags: backup, application, application-server, server-crashes

In a situation in which my primary server fails.I don't want my application to go down but the application to start fetching information form a backup server which is my Pc(Located someplace else) which has a backup pf the Data till the main server is fixed or up !

Comment: And what application is it?  Unless you are doing something with Virtual machines, there is no generic fault tolerance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by looking at using a [load balancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29). It provides a layer of abstraction between incoming traffic and the actual hardware, so if something fails, you can gracefully switch to hosting from another machine.

Comment: what if i am hosting it on a shared server? the load balance and all network facilities will be on his side..If i could have a service running checking the status of the server and detect a fault and divert the connections once the server is down ? easy for me to say !lol

Comment: On a shared server the only way to "divert" connections is to change the DNS zone making it point towards a new destination. You'll have to wait for the new zone to propagate, though.